# How can I jump (e.g., keyboard shortcut) to the first file of the list of the results returned by Windows Explorer after doing a file search?

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer

How can I jump (e.g., keyboard shortcut) to the first file of the list of the results returned by Windows Explorer after doing a file search? I don't want to have to patiently scroll down/up to get to the first file. Pressing <kbd>END</kbd> jumps to the last row of the results, and pressing <kbd>HOME</kbd> jumps to the first row of the results.

Example of list of results returned by Windows Explorer after doing a file search:

[image]

Here is the first file in the list:

[image]

---

I have crossposted the question at:

- https://qr.ae/p7VWxp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no shortcut key solution exists.

However, if you'd like to keep your folders at the top of search results and files below, scroll through your search results faster with Page Down (PgDn) key.  Page Up (PgUp) for faster scrolling up.

Clicking on the Date Modified column heading will bring all files to the top, above your folders, albeit sorted latest modified to oldest.

Using [Advanced Query Syntax](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/lwef/-search-2x-wds-aqsreference) could also help with narrowing to files only results.
For example, in your screenshot, searching with " ext:lzma " instead of wildcard " * ".